# share on facebook not displaying text

Tags: swift, facebook-share

I'm trying to share image along with the content on facebook, but it is only sharing the image. the content is not getting shared.

```
var sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
sharePhoto.caption = "Test"
sharePhoto.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-pic-registration")
var content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: nil)
```

Comment: Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924085/share-image-ant-text-facebook-sdk-4-0-ios

Comment: you want to share image and text on facebook. you can use `SLComposeViewController`

Comment: @Khushbu thanks, it worked

Comment: Nice to help you :)

Comment: i'm using this code. The image is posting on facebook but the text is not appearing. This is my code
`let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        vc?.add(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile-pic-registration"))
        vc?.setInitialText("Initial text here.")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)`